# mmf distribution in rotating electrical machines

Tags: motor, three-phase, electric-machine

we have known in ABC sequence in three phase system,phaseA leads phaseB by 120 electrical degrees, but in mmf vector of electrical machines,mmf vector of phaseB leads mmf vector of phaseA by 120 degrees.
why this two types of the vector have different sequence order?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You have a valid question but please clean up your grammar so it is more readable. Use capital letters to start a new sentence, change things like phaseA to phase A. Please explain the type of machine so we can understand the 'why' part of the question, even though any machine can have arbitrary use of the phases at the engineers discretion.

Answer (score 0):

The rotating magnetic flux is the sum of the flux components produced by the three phase currents. Set time zero as the time when the phase A current is at its maximum. The total flux at that time is the maximum flux produced by the phase A current summed with the flux produced by the negative currents of phases B and C. Continuing with the summations, at 60 degrees, flux is produced by the negative peak current of phase C summed with the positive A and B currents. The diagram below shows 60 and 120 degrees of flux rotation with ACB sequence resulting from 60 and 120 degrees of ABC current sequence.

[image]

The diagram is from Fitzgerald, Kingsley, Umans *Electric Machinery* 4th ed.